# Confused with sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.2

I have the following tables:

```
Customer(login varchar, town varchar)
Orders (Ordno int , login varchar) >>login Fk from Customer
combination (Id int, ordno int ,Product_Id int) >>ordno fk from orders
```

I need to show the products that have been sold in **ALL** the cities.

Example:

```
Insert into Customer (log1 , NY) (log2, NY) (log3, London)
Insert into Orders (1,log1) (2,log1) (3,log3) 
Insert into combination (1,1,1) (2,2,2) (3,3,1)
```

- Product 1 sold in NY
- product 2 sold in NY
- product 1 sold in London

if the available cities are only NY and London, then the only product that must be the result of the query is product 1

Comment: Where's the product table? You can't select the products details if there is no product table.

Comment: Also... What've you tried?

Comment: the city info is at the table of customer

Comment: @SpaceApple asked about product not city...

Comment: This seems like a school project that has been left for the last day.

Comment: Yeah well, don't you remember school times? Oh, wait, probably you were in the same group as me, solving problems for others ;)

Comment: @SpaceApple i just want to return the Id of the product from combination table

Comment: can you give sample records in tabular format?

Comment: @JW웃 Hope this is better

Comment: Ok, this is spec changes quite a lot...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  a.ProductID
FROM    Combination a
        INNER JOIN Orders b
            ON a.OrdNo = b.OrdNo
        INNER JOIN Customer c
            ON b.Login = c.LogIn
GROUP   BY a.ProductID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT a.ID) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT town) FROM Customer)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8d330/11)

Comment: `HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT a.ID)` can also be change into `HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT a.ordNo)` see here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8d330/12

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do here.

```
SELECT c.Town, cc.Product_Id FROM from Customer c
JOIN Orders o ON c.login = o.login
JOIN Combination cc ON o.Ordno = cc.ordNo
GROUP BY c.town
```

This will group the towns together and show you the Product_Id

You still need a Product table to display the product table.

This query excludes the product table

Comment: I want to show the products that have been sold in all the cities. Not the cities

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Products table looks like this:

```
Products (Product_Id int, Name)
```

You need to join stuff all the way down (or up) to customer...

```
SELECT p.Name, c.town
FROM Products p
  INNER JOIN Combination comb ON comb.Product_Id=p.Product_Id
  INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.Ordno=comb.ordno
  INNER JOIN Customer cust ON cust.login=o.login
GROUP BY p.Name, c.town
```